# XML file not found 404 on server

Tags: jquery, asp.net, xml

I'm building out a simple search tool. The back end in XML, the front end javascript/jquery. It works fine locally, but when I moved the file to the test server the xml file could no longer be found, even though the path and file orientation is the same.

I've tried different ways of accessing the file (.ajax, .get, etc) with no luck. **Even if I try just plugging the xml path directly into the address window I am given the same error:** "The resource could not be found". I have verified, the xml is well-formed... pretty much stumped from there.

I suspect this is something to do with the webconfig file (server is iis/asp.net, I have no access to lower-level config), but this is just a guess as I have little experience in that particular arena.

Much thanks for any help on this one!

**Here's the two versions of the jQuery xml retreival mechanisms I've tried. Neither work.**

v1 >

```
$.get('data.xml', function(xml){...});  /*no dice*/
```

v2 >

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {        
    $(xml).find('facility').each(function(){...}
};   /* also, no dice*/
```

Comment: `<suspense>`"I'm building out a simple."`</suspense>`

Comment: Have you tried simply browsing to the file from the normal browser address bar? Also, have you checked that the file is on the same domain maybe, to avoid CSS problems?

Comment: Is the xml file located in the root of your web site ?

Comment: FYI, your two jQuery statements do the same thing; `$.get` calls '$.ajax({ type: 'GET'...})` internally.

Comment: is data.xml in the same folder as your page that calls the `$.ajax()` method?

Comment: Check your IIS setup (or ask someone authorized to do so) and verify that .XML file requests are not forbidden by Request Filtering.

Comment: data.xml is in the same folder as the parsing script. Edited question for clarity (and less suspense).

Comment: Check file permissions... that could be it f you can access the file via the URL

Comment: Doesn't web servers normally separate between deploy and work directories? Maybe you added it to the deploy directory and IIS doesn't monitor changes in the deep, so to say. Just a hunch, I have no recent experience with IIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the server admins had to disabled the XML handlers on the root level of the website. Not sure what that means, exactly, but the problem is now resolved.

Thanks to all for your help!